# How to implement Logstash filters to handle different logfile formats/types

Tags: logstash, filebeat

I am ingesting a number of logs including */var/log/syslog*, */var/log/messages*, but also some proprietary logs in Common Event Format (CEF) and still other proprietary logs in various other formats. The entries of these logs are shot to Logstash from Filebeat running on various nodes, e.g.:

```
filebeat.inputs:
  - type: log
    enabled: true
    paths:
      - /var/log/messages
      - /var/log/syslog
      - /var/log/acme/audit.log
      - /var/log/acme/debug.log
      - /var/log/acme/console.log
```

I have written `dissect` filters for these more proprietary logs. By itself, each filter works, remapping the message field, exploding key-value pairs, etc. to just what I want.

What I don't know how to do is configure Logstash with all of these `dissect` filters active at once, either by running one log on the right `dissect` code log by filesystem path (or origin) or by noting failure of one `dissect` clause and trying a different one instead.

Can this be done in Logstash in the way that I imply? If not, is there configuration in Filebeat that can differentiate the log entries before they reach Logstash in such a way as for Logstash to run different filters for different log entries?

Comment: Perhaps using [conditionals](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/config-examples.html#using-conditionals) on the file name, which should be in the [source](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/exported-fields-log.html#_source) field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Not sure why baudsp didn't post his comment as the answer, but I'll make this more complete.)

The solution is in Elastic documentation
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/exported-fields-log.html. The methodolog to use to tell what fields are available in any given case is to:

1. Fire log entries at Logstash with no defined filter.
2. Create your index pattern in Kibana and examine the list of fields it associates with the data.
3. Whatever is both in the list in #2 above and also in the Elastic documentation's list of exported fields can be coded to (i.e.: used in conditional expressions) in your filter.